# Can't type the letter E in vscode without it running pub get flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

this is bizarre but whenever I type the letter e, it runs pub get and just doesn't get typed on the code, I don't know what is causing this and I am using Flutter. Any idea please?

Comment: Check your shortcut keys.  search for "e" there... you probably accidentally assigned it to that action.

Comment: I've also sometimes gotten "stuck" modifier keys on windows (possibly related to autohotkey) and had to log out and in again / restart. Probably not the problem here, but mentioning just in case.